# Compare image on the page every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I would like to make a userscript (tampermonkey) which will check if the image was changed. The comparision should run every 5 seconds. I am a beginner and I though setInterval will do the job, but after refresh site, the interval doesn't execute. Is any other way to do some code every 5 seconds which will work after refresh? I am also not sure if the comparision images was write well.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Nowy123
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://*/*
// @grant        none
// @include      *.*.*
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
       if (event.keyCode === 79) {
           console.log("pressed o");
           console.log("interval started");

           //image
           let img = document.querySelector('.contentContainer').querySelector('.heroImage');
           var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
           var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
           canvas.width = img.width;
           canvas.height = img.height;
           context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
           var refImg = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
           localStorage.setItem('refImg',refImg);

           let intervalNum = setInterval(specHero, 5000);
           localStorage.setItem('intervalNum', intervalNum);
       }
    });
    document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
       if (event.keyCode === 80) {
           console.log("pressed p");
           console.log("interval stopped");
           let intervalNum = localStorage.getItem('intervalNum');
           clearInterval(intervalNum);
           window.localStorage.clear();
       }
    });

    function specHero(){
       let img = document.querySelector('.contentContainer').querySelector('.heroImage');
       var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height;
       context.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
       var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
       let refImg = localStorage.getItem('refImg');
       let result = isMatch(imgData, refImg);
       console.log(result);
       location.reload();
    }

    function isMatch(data1,data2){
    for(var i = 0; i<data1.length; i++){
        if(data1[i] != data2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

})();
```

Comment: SO on refresh you would have to start the interval again. There is nothing that will make it keep going.

Comment: `setInterval(specHero, 5000)` is the correct usage of setInterval and it should kick off the interval. Intervals do not persist between page refreshes. You could store more data in the localStorage `intervalNum` key and read that key in your top level code so it executes on page load, and re-create the interval there from the stored data.

Comment: I added a few lines at the beginning and this look like it work fine. But the comparision still returns true, although the images was changed.
    `let intervalNum = localStorage.getItem('intervalNum');
    if(intervalNum){
        clearInterval(intervalNum);
        intervalNum = setInterval(specHero, 5000);
   }`